# AJAX fails to get data from input

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, modal-dialog, crud

I am trying to create/insert data into the database, but I am still getting an error for getting the data I've input. I tried using the dump and die method, and I encountered that no data is being gotten from the data that has been input. What could be wrong with my codes?

Here is the result of the inspected element

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZpEI.png)

**My Modal**

```
<div id="modalAddChild" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalAddChild">
    @csrf_field
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Add Child</b></h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><i>Note: In Weight, it is required to put (.) regardless if it is (.0).</i></p>
                <p><i>Note: In Height, do not add (.) if it is (.0) but it is allowed to put (.) if it's any number.</i>
                </p>
                <form id="saveChild" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="mothersname">Mother's Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothersname" name="mothersname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="childsname">Child's Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="childsname" name="childsname" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Indigenous:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="ind_id" name="ind_id" required>
                                <option value="">YES or NO</option>
                                @foreach ($indigenous as $key => $value)
                                <option id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Sex:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sex_id" name="sex_id" required>
                                <option value="">M or F</option>
                                @foreach ($sex as $key => $value)
                                <option id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Date of Birth:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthdate" name="birthdate"
                                placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Actual Date of Weighing:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actualdate" name="actualdate"
                                placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Weight(kg):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight" name="weight" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Height(cm):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="height" name="height" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="zone">Zone:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zone" name="zone" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Age in Months:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ageinmonths" name="ageinmonths" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" id="saveBtn">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#saveChild').submit('click', function() {

        var zone = $('#zone').val();
        var mothersname = $('#mothersname').val();
        var childsname = $('#childsname').val();
        var ind_id = $('#ind_id').val();
        var sex_id = $('#sex_id').val();
        var birthdate = $('#birthdate').val();
        var actualdate = $('#actualdate').val();
        var weight = $('#weight').val();
        var height = $('#height').val();    
        var ageinmonths = $('#ageinmonths').val();
        var dataString="zone="+zone+"&mothersname="+mothersname+"&childsname="+childsname+"&ind_id="+ind_id+"&sex_id="+sex_id
        +"&birthdate="+birthdate+"&actualdate="+actualdate+"&weight="+weight+"&height="+height+"&ageinmonths="+ageinmonths;    

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: dataString,
            url: "insert_child",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == "success"){
                    alert("Data successfully added!");
                } else if (data = "failed") {
                    alert("ERROR IN FETCHING DATA!");
                }
                displayData();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#saveBtn').click(function() {
        $('#modalAddChild').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#modalAddChild').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this)
            .find("input,textarea,select")
            .val('')
            .end()
            .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
            .prop("checked", "")
            .end();
    })
</script>
```

This old ajax is working before but I changed it to the ajax mentioned above but both of them are not working anymore.

**My OLD Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#saveChild').submit('click', function() {

    var zone = $('#zone').val();
    var mothersname = $('#mothersname').val();
    var childsname = $('#childsname').val();
    var ind_id = $('#ind_id').val();
    var sex_id = $('#sex_id').val();
    var birthdate = $('#birthdate').val();
    var actualdate = $('#actualdate').val();
    var weight = $('#weight').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    var ageinmonths = $('#ageinmonths').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            zone: zone,
            mothersname: mothersname,
            childsname: childsname,
            ind_id: ind_id,
            sex_id: sex_id,
            birthdate: birthdate,
            actualdate: actualdate,
            weight: weight,
            height: height,
            ageinmonths: ageinmonths,
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        url: "insert_child",
        success: function(data) {

            alert("Data successfully added!");

            displayData();
        }
    });

    return false;
});

$('#saveBtn').click(function() {
    $('#modalAddChild').modal('hide');
});

$('#modalAddChild').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this)
        .find("input,textarea,select")
        .val('')
        .end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
        .prop("checked", "")
        .end();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

well in your first line off java script you wrote:

```
$('#saveChild').submit('click', function()
```

this is wrong, the jquery submit event only gets a function, but you passed a 'click' event as well.

you should write it like this:

```
$('#saveChild').submit(function()...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the result was still the same.

Comment: another problem of your code is that you set your ajax method type to json, but the data you are sending is not json, is a simple string, you dont need to do that, create a simple js object and pass that object as data, jquery will handle that, like: 
var req_obj = {
  zone : $('#zone').val(),
}

the problem is encoding, do this and tell me if it works pls

Comment: Does not work too. I have this code like this and it is working before, I just don't know why it doesn't work right now. The code is posted with my question.

Comment: The OLD Ajax as mentioned above is working before but now it is not, that is why I changed my code.

Comment: if your old ajax was working and now it does'nt, you need to find out why. maybe you updated a package? or maybe your sever changed the response? or maybe you updated the browser you were working on? it cant happen without reason

Comment: I was wondering if it is because of my modal form since it is all greyed out after the `<div class=modal-dialog>`. I am just clarifying if it is.

Comment: i dont think it is, if you could provide a full code in a sand box, i could try to debug it for you